# Pandas get count of group above group median

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe with categorical column `family` and numerical column `score`, I want to get the count of those by `family` who have above (or below) the median `score` for that family.

Something conceptually like?
`df.groupby('family')['score'].median().filter(lambda x: x>x.median)`

Any help?

Comment: Can you post a small sample data set and desired data set?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be able to assume that all scores are distinct? In that case, all you need is `df.groupby('family').count()//2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like

```
df[df.score > df.groupby('family').score.transform('median')].groupby('family').count()
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want ? By doing this , you can have both above and below at the same time.

```
df.groupby('family')['Score'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x>np.median(x)).value_counts())
```

Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'family': ['a','b','c']*3, 'B': ['d','e','f']*3, 'Score': [1,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,1]})
```

Out put :

```
Out[31]: 
family       
a       False    2
        True     1
b       False    2
        True     1
c       False    3
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```

Bonus :

```
df.groupby('family')['Score'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x>np.median(x)).value_counts()).\
        unstack().rename(columns={True:'Above_med',False:'Below_med'})


Out[34]: 
        Below_med  Above_med
family                      
a             2.0        1.0
b             2.0        1.0
c             3.0        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'family':['Family '+str(i) for i in np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),100)],'score':np.random.randint(40,100,100)})

above_avg = lambda x: (x>x.mean()).sum()
above_avg.__name__ = 'Above Average'
below_avg = lambda x: (x<=x.mean()).sum()
below_avg.__name__ = 'Below Average'
df.groupby('family')['score'].agg([above_avg, below_avg])
```

Output:

```
          Above Average  Below Average
family                                
Family A              9             12
Family B             11             15
Family C             12             12
Family D             15             14
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `lambda` that leverages `numpy`

```
f = lambda x: (lambda v: np.count_nonzero(v > np.median(v)))(x.values)
df.groupby('family').Score.apply(f)
```